# SQLite won't select existing row after escaping string

Tags: android, escaping, android-sqlite

I want to select ID of a row which has a particular name, for this purpose I've used this query

```
String query = "SELECT "
            + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_ID
            + " FROM "
            + DatabaseAdapter.TABLE_TAGS_NAME
            + " WHERE " + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_NAME + "='" + tag + "'";
```

This query works perfectly fine, but unfortunately is subjected to SQL injection vulnerability. For securing this vulnerability I should escape the string *tags*. I've used method `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString()` and the query was looking like:

```
String query = "SELECT "
            + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_ID
            + " FROM "
            + DatabaseAdapter.TABLE_TAGS_NAME
            + " WHERE " + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_NAME + "=" + tag;
```

Note that in this, I removed single quotation marks surrounding the variable *tag* (because they will be added after call of this method).

In this way, the query will no longer work but there are some rows which should be fetched. Also I should say that the tag variable will not contain English string, it contains another language string instead.

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Use **bound parameters**: `String query = "SELECT " + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_ID + " FROM " + DatabaseAdapter.TABLE_TAGS_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_NAME + " = ?";` and pass the `tag` parameter in your rawQuery.

Comment: @DerGolem thanks, your query worked! but I previously tested `... WHERE ?=?` and passing both `DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_NAME` and `tag` and that won't work!, could you please tell me what's the difference between these queries?

Comment: `WHERE ? = ?` is like writing `WHERE 'fire' = 'earth'` as opposed to `WHERE Element = 'fire'` (`WHERE FieldName = ?`).

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks man, could you please write this as an answer? I want to accept your answer

Comment: Sure. Done (the first part only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bound parameters:

```
String query = "SELECT " + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_ID + " FROM " + DatabaseAdapter.TABLE_TAGS_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_NAME + " = ?";`
```

and then pass the `tag` parameter in your rawQuery.

Answer (score -1):

```
        String query = "SELECT \""
        + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_ID
        + "\" FROM \""
        + DatabaseAdapter.TABLE_TAGS_NAME
        + "\" WHERE \"" + DatabaseAdapter.TAGS_COL_NAME + \""="\" + tag+"\"";
```

Use This.